# Handling huge amount of data in Fixed Data Tables

Tags: javascript, fixed-data-table

I am trying to use Fixed Data Tables in my Web Application, I am dealing with large amount of data like hundreds of thousands of records. I am trying to load all the data at a time to make the best use of Search and Sort functionalities of Data Table.

[Here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) is the link to the data table which I am using.

It is consuming huge time to load data, which is expected, but after loading of data getting some glitches in browser, I mean it is getting stuck.

How to handle huge amount of data in Data Tables with complete functionality?

Comment: Implement server side paging, sorting, filtering etc... to the datatable to improve performance

Comment: I am planning to handle at server side only, but in the meanwhile I want to find out is there any better alternative or not...

Comment: @Jaromanda I am sorry it is 'lakhs of data'.

Comment: No code? But I would suggest to go with vanilla javascript instead of a library for loading/rendering lakhs of records.

Comment: "I am planning to handle at server side only, but in the meanwhile I want to find out is there any better alternative or not"  **No there is not.**

Comment: ok, Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using the fixed data table is that you can render the entire table based on an array or an object.

The official link for the fixed data table is given at:

http://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/example-object-data.html

The following link consists of rendering the table on the basis of JSON data. Some additional features like client side sorting and filtering can also be added as you mentioned that the data you have is huge.